# TFLearn Does Not Load Model

Tags: python, tensorflow

Im trying to learn and get the hang of tflearn.  One thing that I have tried to do is save my model, and then reload it.  I get an error that says:

```
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for quicktest.model
```

Below I have my model as well as that checkpoint file that gets created with the saving of a model.  I have googled this error and tried many different file changes but nothing has fixed it.

```
    import tflearn
    data, labels = load_csv('my_csv', target_column=0, categorical_labels=True, n_classes=2)
    net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 32])
    net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 32)
    net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 2, activation='softmax')
    net = tflearn.regression(net)
    model = tflearn.DNN(net)
    model.fit(data, labels, n_epoch=1, batch_size=10, show_metric=True)
    model.save('quicktest.model')
    model.load('quicktest.model')
```

checkpoint

```
model_checkpoint_path: "quicktest.model"
all_model_checkpoint_paths: "quicktest.model"
```

Answer (score 1):

Found out what the issue was:

```
model.load('filename')
```

Should actually be:

```
model.load('./filename')
```

Hopefully this helps out someone else.